# Logging into moneropool

Tags: monero-mining

I'm mining at mine.moneropool.com:7777

When I try to login on their site, I get "please check your login details." I have tried configuring my miner with a variety of different miner ids, and pool passwords including my email, x, no password, and a general string. None of these have allowed me to login at moneropool, though my miner connects to the pool and runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the pools [docs](https://moneropool.com/#/help/getting_started):

```
Required fields are payment address and MinerIdentifier

    Username format : address.paymentID+FixedDifficulty
    Password Format : MinerIdentifier:Email
```

So your password needs to be `your_miner_id:you@email.com`.

EDIT:
Of course the above is for your *miner* settings. When you have the miner with these settings, you can then login to the dashboard with your payment address as username and email address as the password. If you did not set your miner settings correctly, you won't be able to login to the dashboard.